# Database error Missing Driver Name property

Tags: delphi, firebird

Estou fazendo um sistema em Delphi 2010 com Firebird 2.5 que eu seleciono uma base de dados e eu preciso passaro local do caminho para o meu Database no meu Sqlconnection.

```
procedure TFormImportDados.btnBuscaArquivoClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OpenDialog.Execute();
  txtArquivo.Text := OpenDialog.FileName;

  with SQLCon do
  begin
    close;
    ConnectionName  := 'localhost:' + txtArquivo.Text;
    DriverName      := 'Firebird';
    LibraryName     := 'dbxfb.dll';
    GetDriverFunc   := 'getSQLDriverINTERBASE';
    VendorLib       := 'fbclient.dll';
  end;
end;

procedure TFormImportDados.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
 SimpleDataSet.Close;
 SimpleDataSet.Open;
end;
```

Não estou sabendo fazer isso da forma correta.

Answer (score 2):

Fabrício, ao invés de carregar cada propriedade da conexão, você poderia carregar todos os parâmetros ao mesmo tempo.

```
SQLCon.Params.LoadFromFile('conexao.ini');
```

Segue um exemplo de arquivo com as configurações a serem importadas:

```
SchemaOverride=%.dbo
DriverUnit=Data.DBXMSSQL
DriverPackageLoader=TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,DBXCommonDriver220.bpl
DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver,Version=22.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
MetaDataPackageLoader=TDBXMsSqlMetaDataCommandFactory,DbxMSSQLDriver220.bpl
MetaDataAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXMsSqlMetaDataCommandFactory,Borland.Data.DbxMSSQLDriver,Version=22.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
GetDriverFunc=getSQLDriverMSSQL
LibraryName=dbxmss.dll
VendorLib=sqlncli10.dll
VendorLibWin64=sqlncli10.dll
HostName=<Nome do Host>
DataBase=<Banco de dados>
MaxBlobSize=-1
LocaleCode=0000
IsolationLevel=ReadCommitted
OSAuthentication=False
PrepareSQL=False
User_Name=<Usuário>
Password=<Senha>
BlobSize=-1
ErrorResourceFile=
OS Authentication=False
Prepare SQL=False
MARS_Connection=True
```

Comment: Rodrigo.
Está funcionando colando o caminho do banco direto.   
Se eu colocar `'DataBase=localhost: + txtArquivo.Text`' não funciona.  
Se eu colocar `'DataBase=localhost:C:\Projetos\Delphi\CentralRit\db\BDLIVRO.FDB`' funciona.

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLCon.Close;
  SQLCon.Params.Values['Database']:='localhost:'+txtArquivo.Text;
SQLCon.Open;
```